# Does a log-linear leak tell us anything about the properties of the leak?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, boundary-conditions, differential-equations, models

I used a [pressure tester](https://www.amazon.ca/KUNTEC-Universal-Radiator-Pressure-Vehicles/dp/B09FJS1PVQ) on a Subaru 2001 and a stopwatch to record the time and pressure at regular intervals of pressure. I pumped it up to about 17.5 PSI and began recording.

From this data I fit the following model.

[image]

```
                            OLS Regression Results                            
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                 logPSI   R-squared:                       1.000
Model:                            OLS   Adj. R-squared:                  1.000
Method:                 Least Squares   F-statistic:                 2.770e+04
Date:                Sat, 29 Oct 2022   Prob (F-statistic):           7.46e-14
Time:                        16:03:28   Log-Likelihood:                 39.709
No. Observations:                   9   AIC:                            -75.42
Df Residuals:                       7   BIC:                            -75.02
Df Model:                           1                                         
Covariance Type:            nonrobust                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          t      P>|t|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const          2.8593      0.002   1567.950      0.000       2.855       2.864
Time          -0.0409      0.000   -166.436      0.000      -0.042      -0.040
==============================================================================
Omnibus:                        0.626   Durbin-Watson:                   2.298
Prob(Omnibus):                  0.731   Jarque-Bera (JB):                0.533
Skew:                           0.157   Prob(JB):                        0.766
Kurtosis:                       1.850   Cond. No.                         12.3
==============================================================================

Notes:
[1] Standard Errors assume that the covariance matrix of the errors is correctly specified.
```

The coefficient of determination and the visual inspection of the plot below convince me that the choice of model is excellent for this data. The standard errors on the (linear) coefficients are very small, which also hint at the model being very precise despite the small sample size.

And here is a plot of the data (blue) and the predictions of the model (black).

[image]

So it appears that the pressure is dropping pretty closely to what I would expect under exponential decay: the more pressure the system has the faster it loses pressure. Other than that the data clearly shows that something in the measured system is leaking, I am trying to decide if the data or model tells me anything else. The definition of exponential decay in terms of these variables can be given by the rate equation

[image]

with the initial PSI being estimated to 17.45. One speculation is this relationship is implied by the size of the hole causing the leakage being constant. I don't know that rigorously, however, just a gut feeling. Another speculation is that the rate constant `-0.04` would be related to the size of the hole from which air is leaking, but without reference values or a calibration curve I don't see how this can be readily inferred.

What, if anything, can be inferred by the functional relationship between the gauge pressure and the time elapsed since pressurizing?

---

[Here](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/b3e560e35a368b86071afd4522c9260a) is a Python gist with the code and data.

Comment: Seems to me this is linear, not exponential. Very linear in fact. You stated "*the more pressure the system has the faster it loses pressure*." This doesn't hold true on your graph. If it were as you said, the graph would be curved, flattening out the closer it gets to zero. It also seems to me this question could be better answered on the Physics stack or even Mathematics stack rather than here.

Comment: The logarithm of the PSI is a linear function of the time elapsed time, which implies the PSI itself is an exponential function of the elapsed time. My phrasing refers to the pressure, not the log of the pressure. The log-linear function is equivalent to the exponential relationship, but is easier to parametrize in the log-linear form. Although this did help me notice that the legend of the plot is not accurate. Thanks.

Comment: I have asked in the physics.se [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62280554#62280554) about this, although no reply at this moment. This is definitely not a pure math question, but I found it to be toss-up between physics and motor vehicle repair/maintenance.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/17c0b890e03c5e48bbbb63544d3c09ae) is a Python gist showing the same plot after applying the appropriate change in coordinates. And in the comments below that I show that a linear model on the original variables has a slightly worse fit than the log-linear model.

Comment: Nay. This is a Physics question. While it *involves* automobiles, the question itself is outside the realm of this stack. I'm sending it to them for disposition.

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/galenseilis/7ef8d624cf9ad21473f2ed6df66b5858) is a Python gist using Bayesian inference for the parameters, which come out to similar values as estimated by OLS. Related to this data is a statistical observation that can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/594122/why-was-bayes-better-on-exponential-model-rather-than-log-linear-model).